# Python e Selenium: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Estou tentado logar automaticamente no facebook com o código abaixo,

```
   from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    import unittest

class LoginTest (unittest.Testcase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("https://facebook.com.br")

    def test_Login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        facebookUserName  = "myemail@gmail.com"
        faceboookPassword = "mypassword"

        #emailfFieldId    = "email"
        emailFieldID = ".//*[@id='email']"
        #passFieldId      = "pass"
        passFieldID = ".//*[@id='pass']"
        loginButtonXpath = "//input[@value='Log In']"
        fbLogoXpath      = "(//a[contains(@href, 'logo')])[1]"


        emailFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(emailFieldID))
        passFieldElement  = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(passFieldID))
        loginButtoElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(loginButtonXpath)

        emailFieldElement.click()
        emailFieldElement.clear()
        emailFieldElement.send_keys(facebookUserName))

        passFieldElement.click()
        passFieldElement.clear()
        passFieldElement.send_keys(faceboookPassword)
        loginButtoElement.click()

        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(loginButtonXpath)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

o erro que o cmd me retorna.

```
  File "facebooklogin.py", line 29
    emailFieldElement.click()
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sempre que você ver que o problema é em uma linha procure também nas linhas anteriores, geralmente erros de [*Parser* (Análise sintática)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/An%C3%A1lise_sint%C3%A1tica_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) podem ser nestas linhas anteriores, no seu caso o problema é aqui:

```
loginButtoElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(loginButtonXpath)
```

O correto é isto:

```
loginButtoElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(loginButtonXpath))
```

Faltava uma `)` no final.

Comment: Bacana, valeu pela dica !